# resized background doesn't work on start, only if the page is resized

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have a script (I don't remember where I found it) for resizing images based on stage width and height.

My problem is that when you open the site, the background image is BIG, and doesn't fit the stage resolution. When you resize the page, the script works and the image is resized. How can I make it resize when the website is initially visited?

Here is my code:

```
resizeImage = function (getResizeClip)
{
    //eval(getResizeClip);
    stageWidth = Stage.width;
    stageHeight = Stage.height;
    bgWidth = eval(getResizeClip)._width;
    bgHeight = eval(getResizeClip)._height;
    heightRatio = stageWidth / bgWidth;
    widthRatio = stageHeight / bgHeight;
    if (heightRatio < widthRatio)
    {
        eval(getResizeClip)._width = widthRatio * bgWidth;
        eval(getResizeClip)._height = widthRatio * bgHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        eval(getResizeClip)._width = heightRatio * bgWidth;
        eval(getResizeClip)._height = heightRatio * bgHeight;
    }
};
```

and this:

```
myListenerload = new Object();
myListenerload.onResize = function() {

loader._x = Stage.width / 2;
loader._y = Stage.height / 2;   

   resizeImage(eval(bkg_container));

};
Stage.addListener(myListenerload);
myListenerload.onResize();
```

I'm trying put this code `resizeImage(eval(bkg_container));` alone, but nothing happens.

Comment: What is `bkg_container`? A movie clip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `bkg_container`? A movie clip?

Whatever it is, you should bind an "onload" event to it (`Loader`s have this, maybe that's what you are using to load the image) and call that method then. Because if you call it before the image is loaded, its width and height are `0` both. So resizing does nothing.

Something like that in the image loader's instance maybe:

```
on (load) {
    _root.resizeMe(this);
}
```

**UPDATE**: If `bkg_container` is a movie clip, I suppose you are using `loadMovie` to load the backgrounds. If that's the case, you cannot add an onLoad event listener to it, you'll have to do it `onEnterFrame`, or maybe use `setTimeout` so that it does not slow down your movie by the time it loads.

I would suggest you don't use this and use a [`Loader`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00003200.html) component and attach a complete event handler (sorry, I said `load`, it should be `complete`, and that's for the Loader only). That way you could also add an progress event handler to display a loading bar, etc...

There's also the [`MovieClipLoader`](http://www.flash-creations.com/notes/dynamic_loadjpg.php) you might want to look into, but I never used it. The idea's the same.

Comment: `bkg_container` its a movieclip, its a container for my external SWF's with background images...  and the `loader` its a preloader for the site... this not influences on the backgrounds... i will try you code..

Comment: i got this error: `Scene=Scene 1, layer=Layer 1, frame=1, Line 1 Mouse events are permitted only for button instances
`

Comment: The container for your external SWF's what is it? a Loader component? a normal MovieClip?

Comment: its a normal MovieClip, but i try this code below and works fine:

    `onEnterFrame = function ()
    {
     _root.resizeImage(eval(bkg_container));
    };`

Comment: Yes, of course, but this is not ideal, as you will repeat that code on every frame, while you only need to call that when the swf is loaded and when the page is resized. Also, if `bkg_container` is a movieclip, no need to wrap it in `eval()`.

Comment: hum.. my site have only one frame, i call only movieclips and externals swf with action, so, the `onEnterFrame` works fine.. :) thanks for your help... and the tip for `eval()`

Comment: Even if it only has one frame! Try adding `trace("I am running");` inside the `onEnterFrame`, and see how many time it is printed in the output ;) 24 times per second (or 12 or whatever, it depends)

Comment: wow... the trace don't stop...454 until i close the SWF... my Stage is seted 24FPS...

Comment: `onEnterFrame` will call that function 24 times per second. As I suggest in my edit, use the `Loader` component (google it) or visit the link I gave at the end, and a listener to the complete event (or equivalent) to resize it `_root.resizeImage(the_movie_clip_that_contains_the_loader_or_the_MovieClipLoader);`. I hope I'm clear. :)